# Pygame black screen - screen.fill not working after pygame.display.set_mode

Tags: python, pygame, screen

Screen is created, but remains black when tutorial is saying it should now fill white

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a loop to keep the window open. In the loop you should update the screen and have a way to close the window.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

run = True
while run:
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # Checks if the window is closed.
            run = False
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks. The tutorial had pygame.display.flip() at the end but I was running after adding each line individually to see if what I had typed so far worked. I assumed flip meant to mirror the image across an axis, but pygame.display.update() is a more intuitive word for a beginner

Comment: @PaulBranney Yes, if you use pygame.display.update() without arguments it does the same thing as pygame.display.flip(). The difference is if you add a rectangle or list of rectangles as an argument to pygame.display.update(), it will only update that part of the screen.